# How to select a Select Option in the Slim lang Template Engine for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I have a form with the following select:

```
SELECT NAME="partnumber
  OPTION VALUE="7382" steam turbine
  OPTION VALUE="2928" resistor array
  OPTION VALUE="3993" widget analyzer
  OPTION VALUE="9398" fiber identifier
```

The user selects **fiber identifier** and saves - all good, sinatra saves to sqlite db

User clicks a link to edit the form and all fields load correctly except for the above SELECT

I have tried putting the attribute 'selected' after any of the OPTION keywords but it does not work

How do I get this to work in slim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a value to the selected attribute:

`SELECT NAME="partnumber"
  OPTION SELECTED="SELECTED" VALUE="7382" steam turbine
  OPTION VALUE="2928" resistor array
  OPTION VALUE="3993" widget analyzer
  OPTION VALUE="9398" fiber identifier`

Comment: Thanks - I resolved this a year+ ago but since no one else offered the solution the point is yours

Answer (score -6):

It seems you're new to using Slim. Read the docs thoroughly! You'll find mention of a helpful command-line tool that you can run by typing `slimrb`, and entering text (or by passing a filename).

I would practice templating with this tool, as it is really helpful and well written. You would notice, for instance, that you're missing a quotation mark on the end of your `NAME` attribute :)

Comment: Yeah, I read the docs such as they are very carefully.  the example I gave above was typed on the fly.  Since I am running Sinatra I find that Ruby finds the errors just as well.  I solved this long ago.  Not sure but I don't think you answered the question at all - just some pithy advice.  Thanks

Comment: You're blaming me for lack of comprehension, when you didn't explain the problem clearly enough. Do you expect people to read your mind? Sometimes trying to help is a waste of time, and I guess my efforts here were such a case. If you don't want to be civil or sensical please don't add insult to injury by downvoting a response which solved the stated problem.

Comment: I did not blame you for anything.  You did NOT solve the problem - where is the code?  I guess voting down for not solving the problem is an issue here.  I will fix that but otherwise telling me to read the docs does not solve the problem - show the solution is all I was asking for. there was NO condemnation so the emotionalism is wasted.

Comment: Could not upvote but I would if it would make you feel better.  Sorry you took this personally.